# center images with each other in logo carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this logo carousel slider that looks like this:

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.customer-logos').slick({
        slidesToShow: 6,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 1500,
        arrows: false,
        dots: false,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 768,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 4
            }
        }, {
            breakpoint: 520,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 3
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  h2{
  text-align:center;
  padding: 20px;
}
/* Slider */

.slick-slide {
    margin: 0px 20px;
}

.slick-slide img {
    width: 100%;
}

.slick-slider
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
        touch-action: pan-y;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.slick-list
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.slick-list:focus
{
    outline: none;
}
.slick-list.dragging
{
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

.slick-slider .slick-track,
.slick-slider .slick-list
{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
       -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.slick-track
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
}
.slick-track:before,
.slick-track:after
{
    display: table;
    content: '';
}
.slick-track:after
{
    clear: both;
}
.slick-loading .slick-track
{
    visibility: hidden;
}

.slick-slide
{
    display: none;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-slide
{
    float: right;
}
.slick-slide img
{
    display: block;
}
.slick-slide.slick-loading img
{
    display: none;
}
.slick-slide.dragging img
{
    pointer-events: none;
}
.slick-initialized .slick-slide
{
    display: block;
}
.slick-loading .slick-slide
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.slick-vertical .slick-slide
{
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.slick-arrow.slick-hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <br>
   <section class="customer-logos slider">
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/piersolutions/image/upload/v1622549146/output-onlinepngtools-5_fvfhzf.png"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/piersolutions/image/upload/v1622549103/output-onlinepngtools-3_mgtxbb.png"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/piersolutions/image/upload/v1622549943/output-onlinepngtools-4_majmv0.png"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/piersolutions/image/upload/v1622579214/IMG_7500_vyzsxr.png"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/piersolutions/image/upload/v1622579015/output-onlinepngtools-6_dpavgq.png"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/piersolutions/image/upload/v1622579382/IMG_7504_sjpv6t.png"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/piersolutions/image/upload/v1622579288/IMG_6729_rkwddv.png"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/piersolutions/image/upload/v1622579314/IMG_7499_xfzgbt.png"></div>
   </section>
</div>

<style>
  
</style>
<script>
 
</script>
```

but the images are not all centred with eachother, which makes it look unprofessional. I've tried to make it all centred with css, but can't get it. how can I do this?

I want it to look like this pretty much:
https://codepen.io/mdashikar/pen/VWPvgE

Obviously I know that my images are not all the same height, but I was wondering if there's a way to standard centre them or should I just make sure they are all the same height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.customer-logos').slick({
        slidesToShow: 6,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 1500,
        arrows: false,
        dots: false,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 768,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 4
            }
        }, {
            breakpoint: 520,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 3
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  h2{
  text-align:center;
  padding: 20px;
}
/* Slider */

.slick-slide {
    margin: 0;
}

.slick-slide img {
    width: 100%;   
}

.slick-slider
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
        touch-action: pan-y;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.slick-list
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.slick-list:focus
{
    outline: none;
}
.slick-list.dragging
{
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

.slick-slider .slick-track,
.slick-slider .slick-list
{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
       -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.slick-track
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
}
.slick-track:before,
.slick-track:after
{
    display: table;
    content: '';
}
.slick-track:after
{
    clear: both;
}
.slick-loading .slick-track
{
    visibility: hidden;
}

.slick-slide
{
    display: none;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-slide
{
    float: right;
}
.slick-slide img
{
    display: block;
}
.slick-slide.slick-loading img
{
    display: none;
}
.slick-slide.dragging img
{
    pointer-events: none;
}
.slick-initialized .slick-slide
{
    display: block;
}
.slick-loading .slick-slide
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.slick-vertical .slick-slide
{
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.slick-arrow.slick-hidden {
    display: none;
}
.slick-track {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;      
}
.slide.slick-slide.slick-active:before {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -62px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <br>
   <section class="customer-logos slider">
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/piersolutions/image/upload/v1622549146/output-onlinepngtools-5_fvfhzf.png"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/piersolutions/image/upload/v1622549103/output-onlinepngtools-3_mgtxbb.png"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/piersolutions/image/upload/v1622549943/output-onlinepngtools-4_majmv0.png"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/piersolutions/image/upload/v1622579214/IMG_7500_vyzsxr.png"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/piersolutions/image/upload/v1622579015/output-onlinepngtools-6_dpavgq.png"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/piersolutions/image/upload/v1622579382/IMG_7504_sjpv6t.png"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/piersolutions/image/upload/v1622579288/IMG_6729_rkwddv.png"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/piersolutions/image/upload/v1622579314/IMG_7499_xfzgbt.png"></div>
   </section>
</div>

<style>
  
</style>
<script>
 
</script>
```

Like This?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the div element align in center with flex and you can add a light grey background for every element to look better.

```
.slick-slide {  
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
}
.slick-track {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;      
}

.slide.slick-slide.slick-active:before {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: block;
    background: #f4f4f4;
    position: absolute;
    top: -62px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.customer-logos').slick({
        slidesToShow: 6,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 1500,
        arrows: false,
        dots: false,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 768,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 4
            }
        }, {
            breakpoint: 520,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 3
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  h2{
  text-align:center;
  padding: 20px;
}
/* Slider */

.slick-slide {
    margin: 0px 20px;
}

.slick-slide img {
    width: 100%;   
}

.slick-slider
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
        touch-action: pan-y;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.slick-list
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.slick-list:focus
{
    outline: none;
}
.slick-list.dragging
{
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

.slick-slider .slick-track,
.slick-slider .slick-list
{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
       -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.slick-track
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
}
.slick-track:before,
.slick-track:after
{
    display: table;
    content: '';
}
.slick-track:after
{
    clear: both;
}
.slick-loading .slick-track
{
    visibility: hidden;
}

.slick-slide
{
    display: none;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-slide
{
    float: right;
}
.slick-slide img
{
    display: block;
}
.slick-slide.slick-loading img
{
    display: none;
}
.slick-slide.dragging img
{
    pointer-events: none;
}
.slick-initialized .slick-slide
{
    display: block;
}
.slick-loading .slick-slide
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.slick-vertical .slick-slide
{
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.slick-arrow.slick-hidden {
    display: none;
}
.slick-track {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;      
}
.slide.slick-slide.slick-active:before {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: block;
    background: #f4f4f4;
    position: absolute;
    top: -62px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <br>
   <section class="customer-logos slider">
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/piersolutions/image/upload/v1622549146/output-onlinepngtools-5_fvfhzf.png"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/piersolutions/image/upload/v1622549103/output-onlinepngtools-3_mgtxbb.png"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/piersolutions/image/upload/v1622549943/output-onlinepngtools-4_majmv0.png"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/piersolutions/image/upload/v1622579214/IMG_7500_vyzsxr.png"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/piersolutions/image/upload/v1622579015/output-onlinepngtools-6_dpavgq.png"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/piersolutions/image/upload/v1622579382/IMG_7504_sjpv6t.png"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/piersolutions/image/upload/v1622579288/IMG_6729_rkwddv.png"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/piersolutions/image/upload/v1622579314/IMG_7499_xfzgbt.png"></div>
   </section>
</div>

<style>
  
</style>
<script>
 
</script>
```

Open it on codepen to see exactly how it works!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is using flexbox and align items

```
.slick-track
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    // Added CSS Here
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```